# Don't understand a construct in a JS Decorator

Tags: javascript, decorator

I was studying on JS Decorators and don't understand how the wrapper is able to access the inner functions argument. The snippet works, but I don't understand why the anonymous function 'function(val)' gets access to val, the argument of slow().

```
// https://codepen.io/lideebe/pen/VOjGvb

// simple function that gets wrapped
function slow(x){
  return x * 3;
}

// the wrapper function
function cacheDecorator(func){

  return function(val){ // How does this anonymous function get access to val?
    return func(val)
  }

}

// do the wrap
slow = cacheDecorator(slow);

// call the function
console.log(slow(2));
```

Output is 6 and that is correct.

Comment: Javascript closures at work.

Comment: The first example in the dup should clarify things for you. But essentially `cacheDecorator` returns a function, so `slow` is set to the inner anonymous function, which can be called using `slow(2)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `cacheDecorator` returns a function which takes a parameter `val`, and when you call that returned function with the value `2`, it just gets accessed like normal. So `slow`, after you reassign it, is:

```
slow = function(val) {
  return val * 3;
}
```

So `val` is used as the parameter for the argument passed when the newly wrapped function is called.